Python PDF page size
I am trying to get the page sizes of the pages in my PDF. I have tried using both PyPDF2 and pdfminer, I get the same results from both - 423.024x639.024 for artbox, cropbox, etc, and 459.048x675.048 for mediabox (such as what was provided in this solution: Extracting page sizes from PDF in Python) but those do not even match the ratio for the pages extracted as images. When I extract the page as an image file from Acrobat, I get 459x715.
If the dimensions were different but the ratio was the same, that would be fine, but I cannot figure out where it's pulling that 459.048x675.048 from.
Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Or any suggestions on how to get the full page dimensions, so that it reflects the dimensions in the exported jpeg of the page.

How were these PDFs created?   The mediabox is 6.25" x 9.375" , which is usually the intended paper size

They were created from InDesign by our Art team, not totally sure how they convert INDD into PDF though. The page size in Acrobat reads 5.38x8.38.

Do they have InDesign set up to add a bleed margin or index marks?  Even so, none of the "boxes" reflects 5.38 x 8.38.

Bleed margin is set to 36 on all sides it looks like, and yeah nothing it outputs gives me 5.38x8.38" or an equivalent.
